# Does gdal_translate support multi thread?

Tags: gdal-translate

I've seen that gdalwarp has the `-multi` option to use multiple threads. But I don't see that option for gdal_translate. Does gdal_translate support multi thread?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

gdal_translate can **not** use Multithreading for computing. But it can use multithreaded compression for some formats e.g. for [GeoTiff](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) using `-co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS`

> **NUM_THREADS=number_of_threads/ALL_CPUS**: (From GDAL 2.1) Enable multi-threaded compression by specifying the number of worker threads. Worth for slow compressions such as DEFLATE or LZMA. Will be ignored for JPEG. Default is compression in the main thread.

Another Performance Tweak is to extend the I/O Buffer Cache Size using GDAL_CACHEMAX [config option](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions). The following sets the Cache size to 512MB:

```
--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512
```