# How can I improve performance of gdalwarp and gdal_translate pipeline?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

**tl;dr: I can't get gdal_translate to use multiple cores. How to fix?**

I am using `gdalwarp` followed by `gdal_translate` to process a large GeoTIFF by first cropping to a polygon cutline and outputting a virtual raster, then translating the .vrt to a .tif. I have followed suggestions from a few different answers on this site, first I split up the processes into two to enable better compression following [this answer about gdalwarp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89444/file-size-inflation-normal-with-gdalwarp), then I attempted to speed up the performance of gdal_translate following [this answer about multithread support for gdal_translate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241806/does-gdal-translate-support-multi-thread). I am running this on a remote server which has GDAL v2.2.2 installed and the OS is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus).

This is my code.

```
gdalwarp -of vrt -crop_to_cutline \
  -cutline  ${path}/counties_chesapeake_watershed.gpkg ${path}/bigraster.tif ${path}/clippedraster.vrt
gdal_translate -co compress=LZW -co NUM_THREADS=8 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512 \
  ${path}/clippedraster.vrt ${path}/clippedraster.tif
```

My issue is that I don't believe that `gdal_translate` is using multiple cores, though I've tried to specify this with `NUM_THREADS` and also to increase `GDAL_CACHEMAX`. This is a very large raster (~12GB, several hundred km extent at 1 m resolution) so it is running extremely slowly. Can anyone help me parallelize the compression done by `gdal_translate` so this will run faster?

Comment: Couple of suggestions: 1) Have a try by creating the output of gdalwarp as physical tiled tiff file `-co TILED=YES` 2) It would help to have the input image also as tiled 3) Create also the final output from gdal_translate as tiled.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a speedup using NUM_THREADS, but only at the compression stage. gdal_translate cannot used multithreading for any function apart from compression.

Probably the GDAL_CACHEMAX command is helping you out more than the NUM_THREADS option.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful to know. The `gdal_translate` command has been running for 5 days and is only 30% complete so it really seems like I am doing this inefficiently. Is there any way to use mosaicking to make it faster, perhaps?

Comment: How big is the data you're working with?

Comment: The tif is approximately 12 gb in size, with several hundred km in extent and 1 m resolution, roughly 250000P x 350000L

Comment: That's not that large. I believe you're using the best possible configuration using GDAL. If you have access to something like ArcGIS Pro, maybe that can speed up the process.