# Where is the GDAL configuration file after installing via OSGeo4W Setup

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w

According to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241806/does-gdal-translate-support-multi-thread) it is possible to tweak GDAL globally via the configuration file. On the [GDAL website](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html) I found the supposed location of the file - `$(USERPROFILE)/.gdal/gdalrc` - unfortunately, in my case under C:\Users\XXX.gdal\ I only find  the folder "2.4" (although I have gdal 3.7 installed via OSGeo4W). Where else could be the gdalrc folder with the configuration file?

Comment: Why don't you use the first option and add an environment variable `SET GDAL_CONFIG_FILE=c:\\the\path\that\i\want`? By default the configuration file does not exist, you must create it yourself.

Comment: with SET, the variable is only there for the current cmd session - i m mostly working with QGIS, so i would need it globally set with SETX GDAL_CONFIG_FILE c:\\the\path\that\i\want /m  or am I wrong?

Comment: In a way yes, and you have a couple of options https://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/. But in the OSGeo4W installation, when you launch QGIS you are actually running a qgis.bat script that is located in the `[OSGEO4W_root]/bin` directory. You can edit either that bat file directly, or the qgis-bin.env file in the same directory.

Comment: ok, got it. many thanks, if you write it as answer i can mark the question as solved!

Comment: If you're primarily working in QGIS, you can set the environment variables from the QGIS Settings dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it if it doesn't exist in `%USERPROFILE%\.gdal\gdalrc`.
In Windows Explorer file manager:

- type `%USERPROFILE%` into the address bar (or navigate to `C:\Users\your_username`),
- create the folder `.gdal` then
- in that new folder create a text file `gdalrc` and put the config options you want.